# Initializing Google Maps Streetview object looking at the position

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

I have a streetview included in my web site using google API to load it.

```
var theloc = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
var panoramaOptions = {
  addressControl: false,
  position: theloc,
  pov: {
    heading: 0, /* North */
    pitch: -40, /* Look down at angle 40deg */
    zoom: 0
  },
  visible: true
};
var streetview = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("streetview"),
                     panoramaOptions);
```

This works, but I have one issue:

I am interested in loading the view by looking at the position I refer to, but when loading this it always points to north, and the location I specify is not necessarily in view.

If pointing to maps.google.com using URL to open a street view direclty in Google, I can simply omit the heading part of the panorama options parameter (`cbp`) like this:

```
'                                         \/ The heading value space                        '
https://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&cbp=0,,,,40&cbll=58.9582956492561,5.62897047851361
```

This causes Google to automatically center the view on showing the position specified in `cbll`, and I don't need to know what heading to use.

Is it possible to do the same in the javascript API? If I try to omit the `heading` in the `pov` object, or initializing `heading` with `null`, the street view fails to load. I have also tried to set `heading=-1`, but that just points always to north. I also tried to not set the `pov` object at all, but that also always points to north (plus I don't get to set vertical angle 40 degrees down like I want).

Comment: Asked and answered on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068365/getting-the-pov-for-google-streetview-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/47974/initializing-google-maps-streetview-object-looking-at-the-position#comment62612_47974) by [blah238](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/753/blah238) this was already answered on Stack Overflow in this question:

[Getting the POV for Google StreetView API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381895/109392)

So based on this answer, this is possible to do, although not as straight-forward as I hoped it would be...